# How to fit an n dimentional array which is a coulmn of dataframe for x(input) using sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
X = scaler.fit_transform(np.array(data.iloc[:, :-1], dtype = float))

TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

i have data frame of 8 columns and some column contain an array of more than 1000 samples. Now i am facing type error. Please help me to fit a n dimensional array datas as input

Answer (score 1):

Use .values with your desired columns

```
X = scaler.fit_transform(data[["columns", "you", "want"]].values)
```

It seems that you want to skip the last column (I'm guessing because it contains the labels).

```
X = scaler.fit_transform(data[data.columns[:-1]].values)
```

Comment: You actually can't index columns like that, you'd need to index with a list, e.g. `data[["columns", "you", "want"]]`.